# Strange keyword 'metirics' in TypeError message - Keras

Tags: keras

I'm using KERAS (2.0.8) on python3.5 on Windows 64bit PC.

I'm trying to utilize vgg16 with my own full-connect layers. 
But, my model.fit_generator throws TypeError with strange keyword

```
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metirics'
```

Of course, I never use 'metirics' in my code...

Here is my code.

```
def go_vgg():

  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 /255)
  validation_datagen=ImageDataGenerator()

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    save_to_dir=check_dir,
    save_format='png',
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode = 'binary')


  validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    save_to_dir=check_dir,
    save_format='png',
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode = 'binary')


  bmodel = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3))
  bmodel.summary()

  smodel = Sequential()
  smodel.add(Flatten(input_shape=(7,7,512)) )
  smodel.summary()
  smodel.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  smodel.add(Dropout(0.5))
  smodel.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
  model = Model(input=bmodel.input, outputs = smodel(bmodel.output))
  for layer in model.layers[:15]:
      layer.trainable = False

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
                metirics = ['accuracy'])

  history =model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=2000,
                     epochs = np_epoch)
```

The summary result is as follows (I mostely omitted bmodel.summary())

```
____________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
```

---

```
                  .
                  .  
                  . 

Epoch 1/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "test4.py", line 86, in main
    go_vgg()
  File "test4.py", line 80, in go_vgg
    epochs = np_epoch)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wra
pper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2042, in fit
_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1762, in tra
in_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2
273, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metirics'
```

I have no idea where this 'metirics' comes from.
Any help to solve this error would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you are using such a keyword, right here:

```
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
            metirics = ['accuracy'])
```

The problem is that you misspelled metrics as metirics. Just correct it to metrics:

```
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
            metrics = ['accuracy'])
```